# How to show up other pages and posts from your websites in search

Tags: google-search, search-results

[image: Google Search result, showing 6 additional results from the same site]

When I search for websites on Google their results show up like the image above. Links of pages on website are also showing in the search result but when I search for my website only one link with my domain name shows up.

What should I do show up other pages like in the example above "About Us", "Older Entries" and other pages are showing up.

My other pages and posts are also indexed by Google but they dont show up like this.

Answer (score 1):

Google calls these Sitelinks. They're automated and you don't have much control over them outside of demoting them. More information can be found at [Google's Sitelink help page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334).